# How to find the height of only visible elements in the whole html using js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find the height of only visible elements from the html using js or jquery. $(document).height() is measuring the height of whole html element including the height of hidden elements.

Comment: `$( window ).height();`// Returns height of browser viewport
 

`$( document ).height();`// Returns height of HTML document

Comment: The height of each individually or all together?  Please add more notes and code that you have tried that might better illustrate your desire.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can get height of element which is visible by using [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

The `window.getComputedStyle()` method returns an object that reports the values of all CSS properties of an element after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain Individual CSS property values are accessed through APIs provided by the object or by simply indexing with CSS property names.

```js
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.style.width = input.style.height = "20px";
input.setAttribute("height", 20);
input.setAttribute("width", 20);
document.body.appendChild(input);
getHeight();// elemnt is visible


input.style.visibility = "hidden"; 
getHeight(); // element is hidden now

function getHeight(){
if(isVisible(input)){
alert(window.getComputedStyle(input).height); // Javascript way
alert(input.style.height); // jquery way
}else{
 alert('your element is hidden');
}
}
  
// To check visibility of element.
function isVisible (ele) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(ele);
    return  style.width !== "0" &&
    style.height !== "0" &&
    style.opacity !== "0" &&
    style.display!=='none' &&
    style.visibility!== 'hidden';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to get height of window? if so you may use

```
$(window).height();
```

Comment: $(window).height(); is used to get the height of viewport or Screen. But I want to find the height of document. In html I am using accordion, some of the elements may get hidden. So I want to find the height of visible elements of whole html